# How to fix Invalid column index while using query string in JDBC query?

Tags: html

I have used sql statement:

```
select * from tablename where column like ?%
```

in `sql_properties` file.

I am getting invalid column index in my stack trace.

Is it correct?

```
<Sep 1, 2013 4:20:59 AM PDT> <Error> <com.tms.kmcec.dao.jdbc.JDBCGlossaryFeedbackDao> <BEA-000000> <getGlossary: error java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index> 
<Sep 1, 2013 4:20:59 AM PDT> <Error> <com.tms.kmcec.business.object.contentviewer.impl.ContentViewerBusinessObjectImpl> <BEA-000000> <getGlossary: 
BaseEJBException[cause = null errors = null]
    at com.tms.kmcec.dao.jdbc.JDBCGlossaryFeedbackDao.getGlossary(JDBCGlossaryFeedbackDao.java:164)
    at com.tms.kmcec.business.object.glossary.impl.GlossaryBusinessObjectImpl.getGlossary(GlossaryBusinessObjectImpl.java:81)
    at com.tms.kmcec.ejb.GlossarySessionBean.getGlossary(GlossarySessionBean.java:102)
    at com.tms.kmcec.ejb.GlossarySessionBean_mmq58g_ELOImpl.getGlossary(GlossarySessionBean_mmq58g_ELOImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

Comment: would really appreciate if you paste the extract of the properties file, the stacktrace and the table schema

Comment: @dharam sorry i can't get you

Comment: I am asking you to paste the sql_properties file, your stack trace and the table details

Comment: Kindly copy your jdbc/java code and stacktrace exception by editing your question.

Comment: <Sep 1, 2013 4:20:59 AM PDT> <Error> <com.tms.kmcec.dao.jdbc.JDBCGlossaryFeedbackDao> <BEA-000000> <getGlossary: error java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index> <Sep 1, 2013 4:20:59 AM PDT> <Error> <com.tms.kmcec.business.object.contentviewer.impl.ContentViewerBusinessObjectImpl> <BEA-000000> <getGlossary: BaseEJBException[cause = null errors = null] at com.tms.kmcec.dao.jdbc.JDBCGlossaryFeedbackDao.getGlossary(JDBCGlossaryFeedbackDao.java:164) at com.tms.kmcec.business.object.glossary.impl.GlossaryBusinessObjectImpl.getGlossary(GlossaryBusinessObjectImpl.java:81)

Comment: SELECT * FROM  GLOSSARY WHERE TERM LIKE '?%' this is my sql statement

Comment: any idea regarding this issue?

Comment: @user2342297 Remove % from sql query,i.e. try as `select * from tablename where column like ?`

Comment: @polppan getting invalid character exception

Comment: <Sep 1, 2013 5:56:44 AM PDT> <Error> <com.tms.kmcec.dao.jdbc.JDBCGlossaryFeedbackDao> <BEA-000000> <getGlossary: error java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "A": invalid identifier

Comment: @polppan let u check and tel me soon...have to fix this issue..

Comment: @user2342297 If you have source of Java code, kindly paste by editing your question, so that other can point out where exactly the problem is.

Comment: in sql.properties,getGlossary = SELECT * FROM GLOSSARY WHERE TERM LIKE A \

Comment: i specified static input in the query